# Date Format getting reversed upon loading into a table from file

Tags: sql-server, file, ssis, oledb

I have data in the file as

```
08/12/2015 MS
13/12/2015 AUS
28/01/2015 USA
```

When I try loading this data into table using `file source and oledb destination`, the data format is getting `reversed`. 
`08/12/2015`is becoming`12/08/2015`. It has to be in the same format like it was in the file.

Can someone please help me and explain me as why is it happening?

Comment: What database is the data stored in (SQL Server?) and what datatype is the column in the table? If it's something like datetime, there is no format, the data is stored unambiguously as a data, and you can format it however you like using functions like `convert` and `format`

Comment: Yes.. It's into SQL Server. Column is datetime.

Comment: So your data is stored unambiguously then. If you run `SELECT MyDateColumn, MONTH(MyDateColumn) FROM MyTable`, You'll see that the date is stored correctly (it has to be or `28/01/2015` would throw an error). How are you currently viewing the data? In SQL Server Management Studio? There is a way to change your default format - I'll look it up

Comment: How are you viewing the file? in notepad or Excel? Just to be clear: if your data is stored in a datatype of `datetime` and all your data is loading without failure (especially the 28/01/2015 one) then your data is stored correctly in SQL Server and the format you see is just a visual thing. So first run the query I suggested before and confirm that you see the months that you expect

Comment: Please google and learn about how dates are stored in sql server.   It is a common source of misunderstanding.